# Wrong return in assembler function (x86)

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I use Intel x86 for assembler programming. I've got two variables (int), and I want the assembler function to return the biggest. I call the assembler function with a C program, and I've got this in the main(), function(1,5).

Here is the assembler code:

```
            .globl function

            .data
var1:       .long 0
var2:       .long 0

            .text
function:
            movl    4(%esp), %eax
            movl    8(%esp), %ebx

            cmp     %eax, %ebx
            jg      cond1          /*greater, if a < b */
            jl      cond2          /*lower, if a > b */

            movl    var2, %eax

            ret

cond1:
            movl    %eax, var1     /*var1 = a */
            movl    %ebx, var2     /*var2 = b */
            ret


cond2:
            movl    %eax, var2     /*var2 = a*/
            movl    %ebx, var1     /*var1 = b */
            ret
```

The biggest number will be in %eax (movl var2, %eax). The problem is that
the function always returns the initial number in %eax.
For example, function(1,5) returns "1" instead of "5".

I don't understand why the result is wrong.

**EDIT : Thanks to your replies, I've modified the program thanks to your advice :**

```
  function:
            movl    4(%esp), %eax
            movl    8(%esp), %ebx

            cmp     %eax, %ebx
            jg      cond1          /*greater, if a < b */
            jl      cond2          /*lower, if a > b */
            next:
            movl    var2, %eax
            ret

cond1:
            movl    %eax, var1     /*var1 = a */
            movl    %ebx, var2     /*var2 = b */
            jmp     next

cond2:
            movl    %eax, var2     /*var2 = a*/
            movl    %ebx, var1     /*var1 = b */
            jmp     next
```

To come-back in `function()`, I use `jmp`, is it correct?
It works fine.

Also, how can I improve this code? I use variables because the aim will be to have three numbers and find the median one.

Comment: You are comparing parameters passed on the stack, but returning values from global variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confused about what the `jg` and `jl` instructions are doing.

From your code, my best guess is that you're thinking of them as being approximately equivalent to this C code:

```
if (condition) cond1();
```

whereas they actually behave like

```
if (condition) goto cond1;
```

So, there are three possible control flow paths through your function:

1) If the `jg` branch is taken:

```
----caller----.
              |
              v

function:
             movl   4(%esp), %eax
             movl   8(%esp), %ebx

             cmp        %eax, %ebx   
             jg         cond1            /*greater, if a < b */

              |
           branch 
              |
              v

cond1:
             movl       %eax, var1             /*var1 = a */
             movl       %ebx, var2             /*var2 = b */
             ret

              |
   return to  |
<---caller----'
```

2) If the `jg` branch is not taken, but the `jl` branch is taken:

```
----caller----.
              |
              v

function:
             movl   4(%esp), %eax
             movl   8(%esp), %ebx

             cmp        %eax, %ebx   
             jg         cond1            /*greater, if a < b */
             jl         cond2                   /*lower, if a > b */

              |
           branch 
              |
              v

cond2:
             movl       %eax, var2            /*var2 = a*/
             movl       %ebx, var1            /*var1 = b */
             ret

              |
   return to  |
<---caller----'
```

3) If neither branch is taken -- this is the only path which executes `movl var2, %eax`:

```
----caller----.
              |
              v

function:
             movl   4(%esp), %eax
             movl   8(%esp), %ebx

             cmp        %eax, %ebx   
             jg         cond1            /*greater, if a < b */
             jl         cond2                   /*lower, if a > b */

             movl       var2, %eax

             ret

              |
   return to  |
<---caller----'
```

Comment: the GAS syntax make comparisons more confusing because the order was reversed

Answer (score 2):

The value returned from the function is typically returned in the EAX register, which in your case never changes after you load it (you only change "var1" and "var2").

For a simplified version (without "var1" and "var2"):

```
function:
             movl   4(%esp), %eax      /* EAX = a                         */
             cmpl   8(%esp), %eax      /* Is a >= b?                      */
             jge done                  /*  yes, return a (already in EAX) */
             movl   8(%esp), %eax      /*  no, return b                   */
done:
             ret
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not very familiar with the [NASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) format (I use [MASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler)), and I haven't done x86 assembly in a while, but it does not look like you are returning anything from your functions ([cdecl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) calling convention I assume). You need to push the return value on to the stack and then do "ret 4" or something like that.

Comment: It doesn't look like `nasm` syntax to me (so I removed the tag); it looks like `gas`, which means it's likely to be Linux, for which the calling convention is being used correctly.